# Configure IP v6 on Linux machine

Tags: linux, ipv6, ping, ifconfig

I use this command to assign a site-scope IP address:

```
$ sudo ifconfig eth0 inet6 add fee3::216:cbff:fe94:1a86/64
$
```

Check it with `ifconfig`:

```
$ ifconfig
...
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:16:76:5a:a2:6d  
          inet addr:192.168.163.54  Bcast:192.168.163.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::216:76ff:fe5a:a26d/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: fee3::216:cbff:fe94:1a86/64 Scope:Site
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3614 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:596 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:792943 (792.9 KB)  TX bytes:77134 (77.1 KB)
...
```

But ping from another machine failed:

```
$ ping6 fee3::216:cbff:fe94:1a86
PING6(56=40+8+8 bytes) fee2::216:cbff:fe94:1a79 --> fee3::216:cbff:fe94:1a86
Request timeout for icmp_seq=0
Request timeout for icmp_seq=1
Request timeout for icmp_seq=2
Request timeout for icmp_seq=3
^C
```

Where I am wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing some routing. You must tell the router to route all from `fec0::/10` to your given interface.

But be aware that [Site Local Addresses are deprecated](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3879).

Comment: There was a routing error